# Sign of real parts of an analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose that $f(z)$ is an analytic function on complex plane. For all $z\in D_f$ We have $|f(z)^2-1|<1$. Prove (without using Luivill's theorem) That the sign of $Re f(z)$ is fixed for all $z$?

Comment: What is the set $\{w : |w^2-1|<1\}$?

Comment: if $w=x+iy$ then $|w^2 -1|<1$ consists of all $(x,y)$ such that $(x^2+y^2)^2 -2(x^2-y^2)<0$.